# Adding characters to an array list only if it does not already exist

Tags: c#, arraylist, element, infinite-loop

The code below is supposed to read a text file and count all ASCII characters in the file and add up the frequency. Then, it has to write the character, ASCII value and frequency to an output file. The code is below:

```
class CharacterFrequency
{
    char ch;
    int frequency;
    public char getCharacter()
    {
        return ch;
    }
    public void setCharacter(char ch)
    {
        this.ch = ch;
    }
    public int getfrequency()
    {
        return frequency;
    }
    public void setfrequency(int frequency)
    {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the file path");
        var InputFileName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the outputfile name");
        var OutputFileName = Console.ReadLine();

        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(OutputFileName);
        string data = File.ReadAllText(InputFileName);
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        //create two for loops to traverse through the arraylist and compare
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            int k = 0;
            int f = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                if (data[i].Equals(data[j]))
                {
                    f++;
                }
            }

            if (!al.Contains(data[i]))
            {
                al.Add(data[i] + "(" + (int)data[i] + ")" + f + " ");
            }
            else
            {
                k++;
            }

            //i added the below if statement but it did not fix the issue
            foreach (var item in al)
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        streamWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

The code compiles and runs perfectly fine, but the output file is not correct. It is adding letters that have already been reviewed. I've added an image with the output file showing the incorrect output it is creating. --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkLjs.png)

How do I check if a character already exists in the array list? The way I am using is not working properly and I have been working on this for a few weeks now to no success. I have tried using the debugger but this issue will not show up there as the code still runs and compiles correctly.

Comment: `List<T>.Exists(...)`. Wouldn't that be it? Also, don't use `ArrayList`, use `List` instead

Comment: You are testing `al` for containing `data[i]` but you are not storing `data[i]` in `al` - you are storing `$"{data[i]}({(int)data[i]}){f} "` so the test always fails. Why is `al` an `ArrayList`? What is the purpose of all the members and methods (dead code) at the top of the class? Are you familiar with `Dictionary<,>`?

Comment: You could also use a dictionary keyed off the letter instead of a List.

Comment: I have to use an array list, so please don't recommend a dictionary or list.

Comment: Under no circumstances should you be using an arraylist for this. That's exactly the wrong data structure to use.

Comment: Please do not put language names in the titles of questions. Put them in tags.

Comment: This code looks like you've taken a Java program and simply compiled it as C# with minimal edits.  You'll be more successful programming in C# if you use the conventions and idioms of C#, not Java.

Comment: Please do not put output in image files and then link to them.  The output is text; copy-paste the text into the question please.

Comment: There are multiple errors in your program. You say a debugger does not help; you are wrong. Today would be a great day to learn how to use a debugger; by running your program in a debugger you will quickly see why you are getting the output you're describing.  Some advice is here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your comment says "I added the below if statement" but there is no if statement below the comment. Please review your code before you post it here to ensure that there are no confusing comments. **Help us help you**.  You're making it harder.

Comment: Your program begins with a large pile of getter-setter code that is never called. **Please do not post irrelevant code in SO questions**. Again, it makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: @EricLippert sorry about all the errors with the post I wasn't paying attention when I posted. I am just really frustrated with having to do this with an array list as I have a program that works fine with a sorted dictionary and I've been looking at this code forever.

Comment: Break up your program into smaller parts, each of which you can test individually; that will increase your chance of success and decrease the amount of time you spend debugging.  What if you wrote methods: `GetFileName`, `RecordFrequencies` and `WriteResults`?  Your problem is that your writing logic and your detection logic are all mixed up together, so **separate them from the beginning** and test them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ArrayList is not well suited for this task, and in fact ArrayLists are not really used anymore. If someone is telling you that you *have* to do this with an ArrayList

A dictionary would be a much better container for this data. You can use the character as the key, and the count as the value.

Here's one way to do this:

```
var inputPath = @"c:\temp\temp.txt";
var outputPath = @"c:\temp\results.txt";
var data = new Dictionary<char, int>();

// For each character in the file, add it to the dictionary
// or increment the count if it already exists
foreach (var character in File.ReadAllText(inputPath))
{
    if (data.ContainsKey(character)) data[character]++;
    else data.Add(character, 1);
}

// Create our results summary
var results = data.ToList()
    .Select(item => $"{item.Key} ({(int) item.Key}) {item.Value}");

// Write results to output file
File.WriteAllLines(outputPath, results);
```

---

If you *have* to use an `ArrayList` (which no one ever uses anymore, but you say have you to for some reason), it would only be useful for storing the results but not keeping track of the counts.

One way to use an `ArrayList` would be in combination with the `Linq` extension methods `Distinct` and `Count` (first to find all distinct characters, and next to get the count of each one):

```
foreach (var chr in data.Distinct())
{
    al.Add($"{chr} ({(int) chr}) {data.Count(c => c == chr)}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm works, but you are duplicating the output as you are writing to the file inside the loop, that is why you are seeing duplicates in the result. If you move the code outside the loop, it should be ok.

```
                foreach (var item in al)
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(item);
                }
```

I would suggest that your algorithm while correct will behave poorly for performance, you are doing too many unnecessary comparisons, perhaps you should read/check more about using dictionaries to store the results.